# How to Set value Based on Radio-button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My question is as follows. I have a view, with two radio button: Current and History, when Current is selected, the text box year defaults to the current year:

[image]

When the History Button is selected, you are able to enter in your own year: 
[image]

The problem I am having is when I go back to Current, I need the textbox to display the current year again. It currently just holds whatever was last entered in the textbox as seen here:

[image]

**ViewModel**:

```
int _year;
        public int Year
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsCurrentSelected)
                    return AppSession.Repository.Settings.CurrentAppraisalYear;
                else if (IsHistorySelected)
                    return _year;
                else
                    return AppSession.Repository.Settings.CurrentAppraisalYear;
            }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }
```

**View (XAML)**

```
<RadioButton x:Name="btnCurrent" IsChecked="{Binding IsCurrentSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Current" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="btnHistory" IsChecked="{Binding IsHistorySelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="History" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsHistorySelected, Converter={StaticResource EnabledConverter} }">
                    <TextBlock Text="Year:"  Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <tools:NumberTextBox x:Name="txtYear" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtYear}" Width="100"  Text="{Binding Path=Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you call OnPropertyChanged("Year") within the set method of IsCurrentSelected so it updates the UI?

Comment: That actually looks like it worked, would you mind explaining the logic behind that? I had not thought of that.

Comment: So your radio buttons binds to the IsCurrentSelected / IsHistorySelected... you have the year logic on in the get method of the year property. When you change the radio button the bindings are not aware of the relationship, so you need to tell it that this Year property may change now... so re-fire the get method. Does that make sense? I'm not good at explaining haha. I will try and formulate a proper answer.

Comment: @RyanThomas That makes sense, definitely clears it up a bunch. Also, I would leave the other OnpropertyChange in there as well correct? Within the method IsCurrentSelected, there was a                 OnPropertyChanged("IsCurrentSelected");
That can just be left alone right?

Comment: Yes that should be left in there, let's say you added a label or something that was bound to that field, if you removed it, the label would not update. So keep it - even if it doesn't do anything just yet. It's a property so by ViewModel patterns should have it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool _isCurrentSelected;
public bool IsCurrentSelected
{
     get => _isCurrentSelected;
     set
     {
         if(_isCurrentSelected == value)
             return;
         _isCurrentSelected = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("IsCurrentSelected");
         OnPropertyChanged("Year");
     }
}
```